# Jmockit is not merging two coverage.ser files generated using coverage-output=serial

Tags: java, maven, ant, code-coverage, jmockit

I have a maven project I am running junit using argument `-Dcoverage-output=serial`. After each run I make backup of every *coverage.ser* file in diffeerent folder under same parent folder, then I run ant task to generated coverage report. Like this

```
<java fork="yes" dir="myBaseDir" jar="/root/.m2/repository/org/jmockit/jmockit-coverage/1.17/jmockit-coverage-1.17.jar">
   <arg line="-Dcoverage-output=html folder1 folder2"/>
</java>
```

**JMockit** is generating coverage report and *index.html* but not merging two reports. It seems generating report only using the first(which folder is first in argument in ant build file) *coverage.ser*.

Comment: Try moving the `-D` parameter into a `jvmarg` XML element, instead of using the arg line (as shown in http://jmockit.org/tutorial/CodeCoverage.html#merging). You could also try having a single `coverage.ser` file to which coverage data gets appended, by using `coverage-output=serial-append`. If it still doesn't merge, we might need an example pom.xml as well.

Comment: You could also use the [exec-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html) instead of an Ant task.

Comment: Thank you @Rogério. I changed ant task to `<java fork="yes" dir="myBaseDir" jar="/root/.m2/repository/org/jmockit/jmockit-coverage/1.17/jmockit-coverage-1.17.jar"><jvmarg line="-Djmockit-coverage-output=html"/>
   <arg line="-Dcoverage-output=html folder1 folder2"/>
</java>` then it merged two coverage.ser files and generated html file. Please post this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the Ant `java` task does not accept `-D` parameters in the `<arg line="..."/>` element, requiring use of `<jvmarg line="..."/>` instead. So, the task should be used as follows:

```
<java fork="yes" dir="myBaseDir" jar="path to jmockit-coverage.jar">
    <jvmarg line="-Djmockit-coverage-output=html"/>
    <arg line="folder1 folder2"/>
</java>
```